# parent hidden but children still visible (I don't want them visible)!

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, so I had a situation where I needed to add some cloned DOM elements to a parent DIV element in a web page.

I had four of these parent DIV holders. When I make their visibility switch from visible to hidden, a really weird things happens: ALL of the post page-load added children REMAIN visible!

Here is a link to download the source code:
http://www.clarencebowman.com/parent-child-visibility/parent-child-visibility.zip

and here is a link to view the phenomenon first-hand:
http://www.clarencebowman.com/parent-child-visibility

What you will see is a red box with some magenta child elements added to it, post page-load. There is a show/hide button at the bottom of the page.

I added a green stripe in the parent DIV to show that its child elements do indeed inherit its visibility properly.

But after you add the cloned child elements and then hide the parent DIV, NONE of the cloned child elements disappears!

I have already tried placing the child to be cloned inside the parent DIV before running the duplicating script... it makes no difference.

Any child elements that are added post page-load seem to have somehow lost their inheritance link with the parent DIV element (the red box).....

Anyone else experience this? Is there a simple way to repair/replace/re-assign the children's inheritance?

I am using jQuery 1.5.

Comment: try `display: none;` instead of `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: except display none is a property of the css where hidden is a property of the element... I don't understand why it works for most of my code and fail for some exemples...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You're not using `display: none` on the parent (which would affect the children), you're using `visibility: hidden` on the parent, and within the children have a `visibility: visible` css attribute. If you want the children to hide, either set them to be `visibility: hidden` too, or use `display: none` on the parent element.

So, as Kyle pointed out, you can use `$('#parent_div').toggle();`, which will easily apply a `display: none` to `#parent_div`.

I'll just add that `visibility` and `display` are not the same. For example, if an element is `width: 10px`, `height: 10px`, `visibility` retains the element's dimensional space (it still takes up `width: 10px`, `height: 10px`), whereas `display: none` completely removes the dimensions of the element from the parent element (`width: 0`, `height: 0`). `Visibility` means it's still represented visually on flow in relation to other affected elements, it's just not seen; `display` means it's not seen nor represented on the screen in relation to other displayed/visible elements.

Comment: toggle the parent element with `$('#parent_div').toggle();` . It will hide the children.

Comment: @Kyle - Yes, it does; it's using `display: none`. In a jQuery sense, that is an answer, so I added it to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Kyle - When I first learned CSS many moons ago, I struggled to understand the difference between `visibility` and `display`. So I can see how someone might get caught up in that. I've found that in most typical html applications, `visibility` is just not used that often.

Answer (score 40):

Many others have mentioned to just use `display: none` but as you know this has an entirely different behavior than using the `visibility` property.

One thing you can do is to use `hidden` / `inherit` instead of `hidden` / `visible`. `inherit` will cause an element to be visible by default, unless one of its parents is not. Which is what you want.

Comment: `inherit` is the answer!

Comment: The accepted answer of using `display:none` might work in some specific cases (where the element layout/flow doesn't matter), but this answer is a better general solution.

Comment: This should be the best answer!

Comment: just an alternate you can play around with ```opacity:0``` and ```pointer-events: none``` to hide the parent element.

Answer (score 4):

In some cases you can't use the two solutions suggested here.

E.g.
`display: none` won't work because the element needs to know its width and height when it's rendered while being hidden.
`visibility: hidden` might not work if you don't have control of the children and can't add `visiblity:inherit` to them.

In those cases you could add `opacity: 0` with e.g `z-index:-1` to have elements visually hidden (just remember they'll still be there and be clickable etc).

Comment: Opacity is the only thing that worked in my case. Great suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Remove the visibility:visible property from the children. That will fix your problem. You could be using .hide() and .show() (or .toggle()) on the parent instead to set the display to none instead of hidden.